# tableheaderview scroll event

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I use UITableViewController, and I implement

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
   //my code
 }
```

inside "//my code", how can I know that the scroll event was fired from tableheaderview area, not anywhere else in my table, in other words, how to know that the start of scrolling event was in table header view or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually what do you want? scroll in the headerview??? if you want to add a scroll in the header view the call scrollview in tableview headerview method.if you ask your question more clearly then it will helpful to answer.

Comment: I use the mentioned method above to know when my table is being scrolled, I want to know the location of start scrolling, is it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"scrollView.contentOffset.y= %f",scrollView.contentOffset.y); and   
NSLog(@"scrollView.contentOffset.x= %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
```

using these you can get the position of the scrolling tableview.may be it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried that before and I get zero for both contentOffset.y and contentOffset.x, all the time, I don't know why

Comment: It's so strange, the NSLog prints zero, but when I made debug I found it's not, so I think your answer is right, thanks.

Comment: I discovered that it was because I used `NSLog` with **"%d"** while I should use **"%f"**.